# String repeats 20 times in RewriteRule if i try to use it with $1, $2 etc. back-references. Weird. Why?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, regex-group

I try to do a `RewriteRule` redirect in `.htaccess`  where the output URL has some additional text beside the captured text from the capture groups.

Original url: `https://example.com/places/europe/hungary/budapest/`
My regex pattern: `^places/([a-zA-Z-_]+/)?([a-zA-Z-_]+/)?([a-zA-Z-_]+/)?`

i want to add a 'text-' string in the destination url around some $1, $2..

The full line in .htaccess: `RewriteRule ^places/([a-zA-Z-_]+/)?([a-zA-Z-_]+/)?([a-zA-Z-_]+/)? https://example.com/places/$1text-$2$3 [R=301,L]`

but it outputs exactly this:
`https://example.com/places/europe/text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-hungary/budapest/`

Instead of this: `https://example.com/places/europe/text-hungary/budapest/`

Yep, the additional 'text-' is repeating 20x times instead of 1.

If I don't put the 'text-' in the substitution string, all works as expected i.e:
`https://example.com/places/$1$2$3 [R=301,L]`
gives
`https://example.com/places/europe/hungary/budapest/`

What may cause this strange (to me) anomaly?
Is this should work without glitches or what is the correct syntax for this case?

All the other code in the .htaccess file (positioned after this RewriteRule part in question):

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.5]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Yes it's a wordpress install.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Do you have other rules apart from shown ones in your file? If yes then post them in question please.

Comment: Also please do mention FROM Original url: `https://example.com/places/europe/hungary/budapest/` TO which url you want to redirect?

Comment: That's because your destination path and the rule's pattern are same. Try fixing your pattern so it doesn't match the destination URL path

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i updated the question. ALso the TO URL is updated there. I just want to be able to add custom string(s) to the url.

Comment: @AmitVerma no, i tested and the pattern works fine, even if it's same as destination url. It only gives this 'bug' if i try to add some string or text exactly beside a $1, $2 or $3 backreference (like: $1$2 works, $1text$2 gives the repeating 'bug'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comments by Amit that you're running into this issue because pattern `[a-zA-Z_-]+/` matches original string `hungary` as well as the target string `text-hungary`, thus results in a redirect loop.

You may use this rule with a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to prevent a redirect loop as you're experiencing in your current rule:

```sh
RewriteRule ^places/([a-zA-Z_-]+/)((?!text-)[a-zA-Z_-]+/)([a-zA-Z_-]+/?)$ /places/$1text-$2$3 [R=301,L]
```

`(?!text-)` is a negative lookahead condition that will fail the match when `$2` starts with `text-`.

Also note that an unescaped `-` should be placed at the start or end of a character class `[...]`.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thank you so much for nearly immediate fix! If possible, i  would like to know little more about the reason / inner workings of this loop effect / engine. Do you have some link at hand to point me to more info on this? Best wishes!

Comment: Sure, [you can check this doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)